# How to apply scoped stylesheet?

Tags: css, html

Is there any way I can apply *bootstrap.css* only on a *div element* ?
Example: my global class **text-danger** is defined, but for the **#wrapper** I want to apply boostrap.css. So **.text-danger** should have now *color: #a94442*;

```
<style>
 .text-danger {
   color:blue;
 }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <style scoped>
    @import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
  </style>

  <p class="text-danger">Some random text</p>
</div>

<p class="text-danger">Outer text</p>
```

Comment: Do you really want to import a whole framework for one element? Just extract the class surely and add it to your own css

Comment: unfortunately scoped css is only supported by firefox - seems a bit heavy to include a whole library for one div though

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: this is a minor example, in larger application I want to apply bootstrap on a specific portion (div element, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, as scoped css is only supported by firefox, one thing you could do (bit hacky but it may suit your needs) is give your div a class - something like `bootstrap-styles` then you can go through the bootstrap css file and put `.bootstrap-styles` before each style

This will be a lot easier if you are using some sort of css processor like less or sass as you can just wrap all the bootstrap styles in your class

Other than this, you may try a jQuery solution: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

Comment: The jQuery solution doesn't work, tested in codepen.

Comment: Seems to work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mfr0mogx/ (although I didn't try the @import part)

Comment: well, finally I wrapped it and stored it on host or local in a css file. Thanks for the info !!

Answer (score 0):

For only one element you would want to do inline style ()

for a repetitive class throughout your site, you should extract that class styling to a custom CSS/SCSS file of your own and include it.